# Nested hash generation error

Tags: crystal-lang

Given the following code:

```
require "big"

alias Type = Nil | String | Bool | Int32 | BigFloat | Array(Type) | Hash(String | Symbol, Type)
alias HOpts = Hash(String | Symbol, Type)

ctx = HOpts.new
ctx["test_int"] = 1
ctx["test_s"] = "hello"

c1 = Hash(String, Type).new
ctx["stuff"] = c1
ctx["stuff"]["foo"] = { "bar" => 1 }
```

I get:

```
Error in test.cr:13: instantiating 'Hash(String | Symbol, Type)#[]=(String, Hash(String, Type))'

ctx["stuff"] = c1
   ^

in /opt/crystal/src/hash.cr:43: instantiating 'insert_in_bucket(Int32, String, Hash(String, Type))'

    entry = insert_in_bucket index, key, value
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

in /opt/crystal/src/hash.cr:842: instantiating 'Hash::Entry(String | Symbol, Type)#value=(Hash(String, Type))'

          entry.value = value
                ^~~~~

in /opt/crystal/src/hash.cr:881: expanding macro

    property value : V
    ^

in macro 'property' expanded macro: macro_83313872:567, line 10:

   1.       
   2.         
   3.           
   4.             @value : V
   5. 
   6.             def value : V
   7.               @value
   8.             end
   9. 
> 10.             def value=(@value : V)
  11.             end
  12.           
  13.         
  14.       
  15.     

instance variable '@value' of Hash::Entry(String | Symbol, Type) must be Type, not Hash(String, Type)
```

I would expect to be able to create any kind of nested hash but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of things wrong here.

The type of `c1` is `Hash(String, Type)` which is not one of the types of the `Type` union. `Hash(String, Type)` is not compatible with `Hash(String | Symbol, Type)`.

Either include `Hash(String, Type)` in the `Type` union, or give `c1` the type `Hash(String | Symbol, Type)` (i.e. `HOpts`):

```
c1 = HOpts.new
```

You will also have another error on this line of code:

```
ctx["stuff"]["foo"] = { "bar" => 1 }
```

`ctx["stuff"]` will return an object of type `Type` and not a hash as you expect. If you know for certain that `ctx["stuff"]` is a hash (which we do from this example) then you need to restrict its type. Also `{ "bar" => 1 }` is of type `Hash(String, Int32)` and not `Hash(String, Type)`, so you need to specify this too:

```
ctx["stuff"].as(HOpts)["foo"] = HOpts{ "bar" => 1 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: It is better to use `HOpts` alias instead of `Hash(String | Symbol, Type)` everywhere, so you will not need to update it all the time you change a type. i.e `HOpts.new` and `ctx["stuff"].as(HOpts)`